# Read a txt file

Tags: r, text

I want to read a txt file with special format
And import it in R language 
And do all data mining

Below is txt file format:

```
BoxName , hieght , width , color , time arive
```

All the numbers inside the box (unknown the numbers of line)

```
Test.txt
HappyBox, 5,4,red, 2017-5-7 13:00:00
1,4,976,266,625,917,167
1,947,21,5,6,9
smileBox, 8,4,blue, 2017-9-7 17:06:00
7,91,4,9,8,1,5,6
6,9,266,8246,97
754,146,1075,8366,264
JoyBox,6,17,pink.....
```

I hope you understand

Comment: Hi bigbountry , put my txt file is not each line indecate one record , so how can i store multiple line for only on record

Comment: Hi bassie , actually i am beigining for r language so i just try with basic read txt file

Answer (score 1):

You can consider it as a csv file as it is comma seperated.
So,you can just use

`x <- read.csv("flatFile.txt")`